# Does torah study refine one's character?

Tags: torah-study, middos-character-traits

I have met some torah scholars who appear to be learning quite a bit, yet their character traits appear to be in the lacking.

Is torah study supposed to refine one's character? If so, how can we explain this.

(disclaimer: I don't mean to say this is widespread, just that it happens sometimes)

(source for torah study refining character: The gemara Shabbos 88a discusses whether Torah study or the observance of Torah commandments is greater. It concludes that Torah study is greater, for it leads to action. It seems here that our Sages are instructing us that instilling Jewish values in character as well as Torah observance is most effectively achieved through studying Torah.)

Comment: Can you provide a source for the idea that Torah study refines one's character?

Comment: Maybe their character was even worse before?

Comment: @MonicaCellio sometimes yes. not always

Comment: maybe they're doing it wrong.

Comment: Are you asking if Torah study refines character, or assuming it does and asking for exceptions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Torah is studied properly if the goal is to observe that which is learned (*Avos* 4:5). If someone studies the many halachos that have bearing on one's character (e.g. those related to kindness, honesty, alacrity, discipline, etc.) without meaning to fulfill what he learns, that is not proper Torah study, and cannot be expected to improve his character.

The Y'rushalmi (*Shabbos* 7a,b) quotes R' Yochanan that someone who studies Torah without meaning to fulfull it would be better off if he was never brought into the world. The gemara (*Ta'anis* 7a) writes תניא היה ר' בנאה אומר... וכל העוסק בתורה שלא לשמה נעשית לו סם המות, meaning that Torah study actually has a negative impact on those who study it with foul intentions (which is what *lo lishmah* means in this context).

Comment: ok. but the torah is inherently holy and should help one even if he does not have proper intentions as the ramchal says in derech Hashem in the section on torah.

Comment: @R.S. There are different categories of *lo lishmah* - some are acceptable and even appropriate stepping stones that can ultimately lead to *lishmah* (*P'sachim* 50b). Studying in hopes of receiving a reward (which is acceptable, if not per-se ideal) is not the same as studying with no intention of fulfilling the Torah (which is improper) or studying with the intent to misuse Torah knowledge (which is considered poisonous to the soul).

Comment: yes but in my question i'm referring to average people who certainly dont have intent to misuse

Comment: @R.S. It's hard to know that for certain, but anyway that's not my main point. My main point is that if someone learns Torah without planning to apply it, how can you expect him to absorb Torah values into his behavior? The Yerushalmi quoted in my answer is relevant to this type of Torah learning.

Comment: "Halevai oti azavu v’torati shamaru" - "If only they would abandon ME but keep my torah" (Eicha Rabba, Petichta 2). Rabbi Nissan Kaplan explains this to mean - "if they abandoned mitzvot but kept learning, they would be brought back to the good". so it seems torah does have this power.

Comment: @good_ole_ray There are different ways to interpret this statement of Chazal (also found in Yerushalmi Chagiga 1:7). Based on to R' Kaplan's reading, I guess he either holds that this opinion disagrees with the Yerushalmi in Shabbos, or he might make distinctions between different kinds of abandoning the mitzvos (e.g. totally versus occasionally) or between different kinds of learning (e.g. with the intent not to fulfill versus without specific intent to fulfill).

Answer (score 0):

It is worthwhile to quote Rambam's words in Laws of Talmud Torah (4: 1):

> הָרַב שֶׁאֵינוֹ הוֹלֵךְ בְּדֶרֶךְ טוֹבָה אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁחָכָם גָּדוֹל הוּא וְכָל הָעָם צְרִיכִין לוֹ אֵין מִתְלַמְּדִין מִמֶּנּוּ עַד שׁוּבוֹ לַמּוּטָב. שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (מלאכי ב-ז) 'כִּי שִׂפְתֵי כֹהֵן יִשְׁמְרוּ דַעַת וְתוֹרָה יְבַקְשׁוּ מִפִּיהוּ כִּי מַלְאַךְ ה' צְבָאוֹת הוּא'. אָמְרוּ חֲכָמִים אִם הָרַב דּוֹמֶה לְמַלְאַךְ ה' צְבָאוֹת תּוֹרָה יְבַקְּשׁוּ מִפִּיהוּ אִם לָאו אַל יְבַקְּשׁוּ תּוֹרָה מִפִּיהוּ

That is: a rabbi who behaves improperly, **even if he is a great sage whom the entire nation depends upon**; we do not learn from him until he returns to proper conduct.

This certainly implies that one can gain Torah knowledge without improving ones character.